# Pytorch loss is nan

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to write my first neural network with pytorch.
Unfortunately, I encounter a problem when I want to get the loss.
The following error message:

```
RuntimeError: Function 'LogSoftmaxBackward0' returned nan values in its 0th output.
```

So I tried debugging and found something strange.
The input has no nans and infs as I verify with the following:

```
print(torch.any(torch.isnan(inputs)))
```

But if I always let the individual steps in the model x be output, I see that there will be inf at some point.

training

```
inputs, labels = data
print(torch.any(torch.isnan(inputs)))
optimizer.zero_grad()
outputs = model(inputs)
print(outputs)
loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
print(f"epoch: {epoch + 1} loss: {loss.item()}")
loss.backward()

optimizer.step()
```

model

```
class Net(Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.layer1 = Conv1d(in_channels=1, out_channels=5, kernel_size=5, stride=2, dtype=torch.float64)
        self.act1 = ReLU()
        self.pool1 = MaxPool1d(2)
        self.layer2 = Conv1d(in_channels=5, out_channels=1, kernel_size=2, dtype=torch.float64)
        self.fcl1 = Linear(1350, 16, dtype=torch.float64)

    def forward(self, x):
        print("raw", x)
        x = self.layer1(x)
        print("conv1d 1", x)
        x = self.act1(x)
        print("relu", x)
        x = self.layer2(x)
        print("conv1d 2", x)
        x = self.pool1(x)
        x = self.pool1(x)
        x = self.pool1(x)
        x = self.pool1(x)
        x = self.pool1(x)
        x = self.pool1(x)
        x = self.pool1(x)
        print("pools", x)
        x = self.fcl1(x)
        print("linear", x)
        return x
```

output

```
tensor(False)
raw tensor([[9.0616e+227, 2.4353e-152,  1.0294e-71,  ...,  0.0000e+00,
          0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00]], dtype=torch.float64)
conv1d 1 tensor([[   -inf,    -inf,    -inf,  ..., -0.2516, -0.2516, -0.2516],
        [    inf,     inf,     inf,  ...,  0.3377,  0.3377,  0.3377],
        [   -inf,    -inf,    -inf,  ...,  0.4285,  0.4285,  0.4285],
        [   -inf,    -inf,    -inf,  ..., -0.1230, -0.1230, -0.1230],
        [    inf,     inf,     inf,  ...,  0.3793,  0.3793,  0.3793]],
       dtype=torch.float64, grad_fn=<SqueezeBackward1>)
relu tensor([[0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000,  ..., 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
        [   inf,    inf,    inf,  ..., 0.3377, 0.3377, 0.3377],
        [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000,  ..., 0.4285, 0.4285, 0.4285],
        [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000,  ..., 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
        [   inf,    inf,    inf,  ..., 0.3793, 0.3793, 0.3793]],
       dtype=torch.float64, grad_fn=<ReluBackward0>)
conv1d 2 tensor([[        -inf,         -inf,         -inf,  ..., -5.4167e+265,
         -5.4167e+265, -5.4167e+265]], dtype=torch.float64,
       grad_fn=<SqueezeBackward1>)
pools tensor([[        -inf, -5.4167e+265, -5.4167e+265,  ..., -5.4167e+265,
         -5.4167e+265, -5.4167e+265]], dtype=torch.float64,
       grad_fn=<SqueezeBackward1>)
linear tensor([[inf, inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, -inf, inf, inf, -inf, -inf]],
       dtype=torch.float64, grad_fn=<AddmmBackward0>)
tensor([[inf, inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, -inf, inf, inf, -inf, -inf]],
       dtype=torch.float64, grad_fn=<AddmmBackward0>)
epoch: 1 loss: nan
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 6):

Sorry, my reputation is not enough for me to comment directly. This may be caused by the exploding gradient due to the excessive learning rate. It is recommended that you reduce the learning rate or use weight_decay.

Comment: I tried very low learning rates like 0.0000001. It doesn't helps.

Comment: Sorry I didn't check your code in detail. It can be seen that your output appears inf after going through conv1d, this may be because you did not normalize, so you will get a large value when doing convolution. Please output the original data to check, if the original data is large, please normalize it.

Answer (score 2):

If it is an error in the 0th output, that means your weights are still not fully updates so some values in your first predictions are nans. So it's not your inputs, but your model predictions that are nans. Could be an overflow or underflow error. This will make any loss function give you a `tensor(nan)`.What you can do is put a check for when loss is nan and let the weights adjust themselves

```py
criterion = SomeLossFunc()
eps = 1e-6
loss = criterion(preds,targets)
if loss.isnan(): loss=eps
else: loss = loss.item()
loss = loss+ L1_loss + ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Common causes for NAN loss

1. the learning rate is too high
2. faulty input:

```
# check if input has zeros 
numpy.all(x) # return True if there are zeros, otherwise return False

# check if input has nans 
numpy.any(numpy.isnan(x)) # return True if there are nans, otherwise return False
```

3. faulty loss function(not likely when using built-in funcitons)

Comment: What if I don't get any error but it just shows me that the loss is nan? What should I do? I did create a customized `torch.autograd.Function`.